# Get `Inconsistent state for stream ` when integrating Heroku with AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, heroku-postgres, stitch

When trying to integrate between from Heroku PostgreSQL DB and AWS Postgresql USING stitch data (stitchdata.com) I get the following message without much explanation:

```
Inconsistent state for stream DBNAME-public-addresses with replication method: null, and bookmark: {}
```

What is causing this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you find the resolution for this issue? Am also facing the same issue.

Comment: I did not find a solution.

Comment: I am facing the same error on Stitch Date while creating a central data warehouse (AWS S3) and trying to first connect my PostgreSQL database which is on Heroku.

Comment: @kunsterD93 Ever figure this out?

Comment: @JonathanCrawford Unfortunately no. Did you?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. The cause is a misleading Stitch settings interface.

Every table you've selected to be synced from a Postgres DB by Stitch needs a "replication method" - options are "Full table" and "Key-based incremental". "Key-based incremental" means only syncing rows whose value is greater than the last row in the previous sync. Think `created_at`.

When you select a table to by synced from a Postgres DB by Stitch, it will prompt you for a replication method. However, when you select all tables at once using the checkbox in the top left of the list of tables, you aren't prompted for anything at all. Stitch will allow you to save a configuration with no replication methods on any table, which will immediately fail with the cryptic `Inconsistent state` error in the question.

So, to solve:

1. open your integration settings
2. navigate to "Tables to replicate"
3. manually un-check and re-check each table to be synced
4. select a replication method when prompted

There is no way to set a replication setting for more than one table at once; it has to be done for each table. When you've done this for all of them, this error will stop being thrown.